# Repetitive mysql execution by woocommerce in Wordpress

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

The MySQL process is using very high CPU, 157.5% in top command. So I found the process list in MySQL never disappears for the query of :

```
SELECT post_name FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name = 'woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async...
```

Any ideas what is that doing? Are they important? How to stop them?

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
+-----+------+-----------+-------+---------+------+----------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| Id  | User | Host      | db    | Command | Time | State          | Info                                                                                                                                                 | Progress |
+-----+------+-----------+-------+---------+------+----------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| 555 | root | localhost | wp    | Query   |    0 | statistics     | SELECT post_name FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name = 'woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async-5849' AND post_type = 'scheduled-action' AND ID != 20333 LIMIT 1 |    0.000 |
| 568 | root | localhost | wp    | Sleep   |    0 |                | NULL                                                                                                                                                 |    0.000 |
| 583 | root | localhost | wp    | Query   |    0 | statistics     | SELECT post_name FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name = 'woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async-61' AND post_type = 'scheduled-action' AND ID != 20365 LIMIT 1   |    0.000 |
| 587 | root | localhost | NULL  | Query   |    0 | init           | SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST                                                                                                                                |    0.000 |
| 591 | root | localhost | wp    | Query   |    0 | Writing to net | SELECT post_name FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name = 'woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async-7885' AND post_type = 'scheduled-action' AND ID != 20291 LIMIT 1 |    0.000 |
| 592 | root | localhost | wp    | Query   |    0 | statistics     | SELECT post_name FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name = 'woocommerce_deliver_webhook_async-7912' AND post_type = 'scheduled-action' AND ID != 20391 LIMIT 1 |    0.000 |
+-----+------+-----------+-------+---------+------+----------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
```

Comment: Is it related to this? https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/19634

Comment: @markmoxx It's related, but I am not sure how to find the stucked "pending" webhook, not familiar in wordpress system. Also I tried deleting the 'cron' option in the wp_options table as suggested, it does not help.

Comment: Have you viewed on the admin WordPress dashboard the page WooCommerce -> Settings -> Advanced -> Webhooks? Does it show the webhook?

Comment: @user8262086 Empty (disabled) webhook keep auto increase by itself now is at 3395, see the picture https://ibb.co/QQrtGsr 

It stopped after I have temporary modify the file wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\libraries\action-scheduler\classes\ActionScheduler_QueueRunner.php from everyminute to twicedaily, i assume that is a scheduler to run other crons, I have no crons that require every minute execution, so I make it less often. I want a permanent fix to this though, my guess this get messed up when I migrated to new server.